# populate data frame with file.info using apply function

Tags: r, apply

I would like to populate an existing empty dataframe with file information using a list and the `file.info` function. I've been doing the same task using a `for` loop, but would like to learn how to use the `apply` family and thought this would be a nice easy example.

My list...

```
listOfFiles_M <- c("I:\\temp\\APIS2//APIS01/WAV/APIS01_20170414_150000.wav", "I:\\temp\\APIS2//APIS01/WAV/APIS01_20170414_160000.wav", 
"I:\\temp\\APIS2//APIS01/WAV/APIS01_20170414_170000.wav", "I:\\temp\\APIS2//APIS01/WAV/APIS01_20170414_180000.wav"
)
```

My empty dataframe...

```
m_files <- structure(list(size = numeric(0), isdir = logical(0), mode = structure(integer(0), class = "octmode"), 
    mtime = structure(numeric(0), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    )), ctime = structure(numeric(0), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    )), atime = structure(numeric(0), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    )), exe = character(0)), .Names = c("size", "isdir", "mode", 
"mtime", "ctime", "atime", "exe"), row.names = character(0), class = "data.frame")
```

My function...

```
test.info <- function(i,x){
  print (i)
  x[i,]=c(file.info(i))
}
```

And I thought I should use `lapply` thusly...

```
lapply(listOfFiles_M, test.info)
```

And here is an example of what I would like a populated `m_files` to look like...

```
m_files <- structure(list(rn = c("I:\\temp\\APIS2//APIS01/WAV/APIS01_20170414_150000.wav", 
"I:\\temp\\APIS2//APIS01/WAV/APIS01_20170414_160000.wav", "I:\\temp\\APIS2//APIS01/WAV/APIS01_20170414_170000.wav", 
"I:\\temp\\APIS2//APIS01/WAV/APIS01_20170414_180000.wav"), size = c(9601276, 
9601276, 9601276, 9601276), isdir = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
), mode = structure(c(438L, 438L, 438L, 438L), class = "octmode"), 
    mtime = structure(c(1492200300, 1492203900, 1492207500, 1492211100
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), ctime = structure(c(1537974713.78911, 
    1537974713.85152, 1537974713.89832, 1537974713.92952), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), atime = structure(c(1537974713.78911, 1537974713.85152, 
    1537974713.89832, 1537974713.92952), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), exe = c("no", "no", "no", "no")), .Names = c("rn", 
"size", "isdir", "mode", "mtime", "ctime", "atime", "exe"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT: I should have also mentioned that there is a large list, ~200,000 items, so `rbind` is probably not a good solution.

Comment: Your function needs a return value, but in my opinion, it would be better to drop the `x` argument from the function and instead do `x[] <- lapply(m_files, file.info)` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass your list of files into `file.info` which can receive more than 1 value as input and returns a data frame as according to docs, `?file.info`.

```
final_df <- file.info(listOfFiles_M)
```

No need to initialize an empty data frame and map values to it or `rbind` iterative returned objects.

Comment: See my most recent edit. I'm not sure `rbind` will work for me since `listOfFiles_M` is a list of 200,000 files.

Comment: Forgive me, but did you attempt `do.call`? These are one-row data frames.

Comment: It took 13.08 minutes to `rbind` 129,029 data frames. I guess I thought there would be a faster way.

Comment: You actually do not need `lapply` or `do.call` as `file.info` can take a character vector of files returning a single data frame. See edit.

Comment: Curious, was the direct `file.info()` call faster?

Comment: No, but simpler. The direct `file.info()` call took 16.99 minutes to run on the same 129,029 files.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the function `file.info` is designed to take a name of a file and then spit out a vector of length 7 which you use to populate a row.

Just a recommendation, this is a bit hard to test when we do not have `file.info` function's output for at least 1 file. So I would recommend simplifying your m_files data frame when you post.

I believe the only issue is that you need to specify the x argument in your lapply.

```
 lapply(listOfFiles_M, test.info, x = m_files)
```

the `...` argument in apply is for you to list other arugments the function you pass apply may need, in this case it is `test.info`.